# Normalizing functions without actually applying it in Haskell

Tags: haskell, normalization, evaluation, lambda-calculus

I would like to evaluate a function to its normal form without applying it, for example,

```
\n -> n + sum [1..100]
```

should be evaluated to

```
\n -> n + 5050
```

But there's no `NFData` instance for functions, which is reasonable since we cannot obtain the subterms of a function.

I'm wondering if it's possible to fully normalize a function with the help of some compiler magic.

Comment: Checking [`Control.DeepSeq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.3.0.1/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html) I have noticed that the `NFData` instance of `(a -> b)` has a note attached reading *This instance is for convenience and consistency with seq. This assumes that WHNF is equivalent to NF for functions.*

Comment: @Redu but that note is saying it specifically doesn't do what the OP wants

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible. However, in most cases, it is not needed. I suspect that the trick you're missing is lifting the expensive calculations that don't depend on the output out via let. Compare:

```
-- recomputes `sum [1..100]` each time you apply it to an argument
f1 :: Int -> Int
f1 n = n + sum [1..100]

-- computes `sum [1..100]` just once, then uses the "cached" result each time
-- you apply it to an argument
f2 :: Int -> Int
f2 = let s = sum [1..100] in \n -> n + s
```

Function `f1` is expensive every time you use it. Function `f2` is expensive the first time you use it, but cheap every time thereafter.

(This answer is specific to GHC. Other compilers, if they some time exist, may behave differently.)

Comment: Be careful with this kind of lifting. It can have severe performance hits in some cases. Keeping a a large value in memory can slow down the garbage collector far more than it saves on recomputation.

Comment: Do you know why when i do like `s = sum [1..100]` and then `t = Control.DeepSeq.deepseq s ()` and then `:sprint s` i still get `s = _` while `t` becomes `()`.

Comment: Let me guess, it's impossible because functional definitions are "hardcoded" and normalizing a function requires a recompilation right?

Comment: @Redu I think it because it can't be reduced further, since it doesn't know the type of `s :: (Num a, Enum a) => a`. If you do something like `s = sum [1..100] :: Int` and `:sprint` that you'll even get `s = 5050`. It doesn't need extra information for it to resolve to `()`.

Comment: @Redu Because `s` has been inferred to be typeclass-polymorphic. Choose a type -- for example, by writing `s :: Int; s = sum [1..100]` -- and you will not have this problem. For more details, google "monomorphism restriction"; the motivation for the restriction talks is exactly this problem.

Comment: @Poscat I think the thing you're asking for is more subtle and complicated than you are imagining. Consider `\x -> x || someExpensiveThingThatDoesNotDependOnX`. Should evaluating this to normal-form evaluate `someExpensiveThingThatDoesNotDependOnX`? It's not clear to me it should; after all, if you supply `True` as an argument, that evaluation is not required. It probably isn't possible to design something that does evaluation in an open context and doesn't ever surprise you.

Comment: @Caramiriel Many thanks you for your feedback.. However it doesn't automatically evaluate when done like `w = sum [1..100] :: Int`  and then `:sp w` still shows `w : _`. I believe this is normal since it would render `seq` useless otherwise and every type signature would introduce strictness. Yet... `seq w ()` and `:sp w` gives `w = 5050`. OK i goıt it.. the type signature must be defined beforehand `seq`ing.

Comment: @Poscat, there are evaluation strategies that are capable of this, eg lazy specialization and optimal evaluation. But they have quite a lot of overhead; the simple graph reduction that GHC does is a lot faster for most programs.  But there are certain classes of programs that could benefit greatly from these other strategies, and I've always wondered what we could create if we could plug GHC into a lazy specializer...